# ruby help debugging with infinite loop from input of text file

Tags: ruby, loops, input, text-files, infinite

So I don't understand why when I print var It prints the list of 50 items infinitely. I'm a Java guy so maybe I'm missing something. I'm trying to get a list of strings line by line and read them into the array. Want to sort them after but can't get past infinite loop of list items.

```
puts "Hello, Ruby!";
    #Declare variable for list
    var1 = [50]

    #Read in words
    #opening file
    count = 0;

    while count < 50
      File.open("text.txt", "r") do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
      var1[count] = line
      count += 1
      end

    end
    puts "hey guys"
    puts var1

    end
```

Comment: Never mind. The code works very well my list should start at 49.

Comment: note that `var1 = [50]` does not create an array of length 50 in ruby, it creates an array with one item in it, and that item is the Fixnum 50.  As @tadman mentions, you only need to do `var1 = []` as `[]` is an alias for Array.new, but nobody uses that except when they want to pass args to .new.  You can specify a length when using .new but there's rarely a need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more Ruby way of tackling this problem:

```
puts "Hello, Ruby!"

array = [ ]

while (array.length < 50)
  File.open("text.txt", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      array << line.chomp
    end
  end
end

# Trim to the first 50 lines
array = array.first(50)
```

Note that `;` is not supposed to be used after statements. It's allowed if you need to separate things for the purposes of writing more minimal code, but even that is discouraged. Normally it's reserved for tiny one-liners, things like `class X; end` as an example.